Comparing Motor Starting Methods: Star to DOL vs. Star to Delta
Question:
I need to understand the differences between the two motor-starting methods:
Case 1: Start with a Star connection and then switch to DOL (Direct-On-Line)  [I know this is not standard configuration but trying to understand this].
Case 2: Start with a Star connection and then switch to Delta.
Please provide a detailed comparison in table format, including the following aspects:
What are the real-world differences between Case 1 and Case 2? Which method is generally better and why?
Note: I am aware of the commonalities but need a clear understanding of the distinctions, including any advantages or disadvantages of each method.
More Context: I'm asking this question because we're in the process of buying an air compressor in our woodworking factory. The company handling the installation mentioned they'd be using a star-delta configuration, so I took the initiative to research the differences between DOL and star-delta configurations. While I understood why star-delta might be preferred over DOL, it led me to a new question: How would a Star-DOL configuration compare to star-delta?
Since Star-DOL isn't a standard configuration, I'm reaching out for expert opinions, as I couldn't find any relevant information online.
P.S.: I'm not an electrical engineer or a student; I'm simply trying to deepen my understanding. If you review the question carefully, you'll notice it's not just a comparison of DOL versus star-delta but specifically about how Star-DOL compares to star-delta.
To clarify, my question is:
-> Case 1: Start the motor on Star and then shift to DOL
-> Case 2: Start on Star and then shift to Delta
I am trying to understand the difference between Case 1 Vs Case 2.

I think you’ll find star-DOL is simply star-delta. With delta, the motor windings are phase to phase thus they get 380VAC or whatever your local 3phase is rated at. For larger motors, normally many kW, it can be useful to start the motor in ‘star’ which means the motor windings only get 220VAC (or whatever you local single phase voltage is) and as a result, the startup current is less. After a few seconds a timer switches over the delta thus giving the motor the full voltage.
DOL just runs the motor in delta - no startup sequence just ‘direct on line’.
You should be asking the question to your contractor. If he can’t give you an answer I’d suggest looking for another contractor.

DOL and Delta connections differ in their physical connection configuration. Notably, the line current in a Delta connection is √3 times the phase current (I), unlike the DOL connection where it equals the phase current. This difference in current magnitude suggests that DOL and Delta connections can yield varying performance outcomes. So, are we still right when we say DOL just run motor is Delta?

@kautuksahni I think you mean the line current in the star connection is root 3 . Delta has the windings phase to phase, star has the windings phase to neutral. The phase to neutral voltage is root 3 of the phase to phase voltage.
